# A complex sql issue

Tags: sql

I have these 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer]
(
    [CustomerName]  VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
    [CustomerLink]  VARCHAR(40)  NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomerIdentification]
(
    [CustomerName]  VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
    [ID]            VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    [IDType]        VARCHAR(16)  NOT NULL
)
```

And I've added some test data..

```
INSERT  [dbo].[Customer]
        ([CustomerName])
VALUES  ('Fred'),
        ('Bob'),
        ('Vince'),
        ('Tom'),
        ('Alice')

INSERT  [dbo].[CustomerIdentification]
VALUES  
        ('Fred',   'A',  'Passport'),
        ('Fred',   'A',  'SIN'),
        ('Fred',   'A',  'Drivers Licence'),
        ('Bob',    'A',  'Passport'),
        ('Bob',    'B',  'Drivers Licence'),
        ('Bob',    'C',  'Credit Card'),
        ('Vince',  'A',  'Passport'),
        ('Vince',  'B',  'SIN'),
        ('Vince',  'C',  'Credit Card'),
        ('Tom',    'A',  'Passport'),
        ('Tom',    'B',  'SIN'),
        ('Tom',    'A',  'Drivers Licence'),
        ('Alice',  'B',  'Drivers Licence')
```

Basically, a customer (from customer table) can have many pieces of identifications. For instance, Fred has passport, sin and drivers license and all 3 has value is A (the value could be different too).

This is the output I want:

*Test 1: Passport with value A*

From the table: first common identification is Passport with value A: 4 Customers have this ID. Fred, Bob, Vince and Tom and maybe they are all the same customer, if thats the case, we would like to link all 4 of them with a unique ID (guid) in customer table's CustomerLink field.

However, if 1 ID matches between customers, then others should match too if any of them have other common IDType. For example, Fred also has SIN with a value of A which also exist on Vince and Tom but with a value of B. So this group is not the same customer. No linking done.

*Test 2: SIN with value B*

Next common identification is SIN with value B which exist for Vince and Tom. Vince and Tom are indeed same customer since they also have Passport with same value (A). The 3rd identification for both have different IDType, credit card and drivers license. Hence they can be linked. So we link vince and Tom as same customer in customer table.

*Test 3: Drivers license with value A*

Which exists for Fred and Tom. Both have passport with value A too. Both have SIN common as well, however, the value of SIN is different for both. Its A for Fred and B for Tom. Hence they are not the same customer. No linking done.

*Test 4: Drivers license with value B*

Which exists for Bob and Alice. They are indeed the same customer since Bob and Alice both have Drivers license with value B. Bob has 2 other pieces of ID which alice does not have, and that is fine since those Ids are unique to Bob. So we link Bob and Alice as same customer in customer table.

*Test 5: Credit Card with value C*

Which exists for Bob and Vince.

But Bob is already linked to Alice so we have to bring Alice into the picture.
And Vince is already linked to Tom so we have to bring Tom into the picture.

Now, Bob has Drivers License with value B and Tom also has Drivers license with value A. Different values but same ID (drivers license) cause this group to not link. Hence, no linking done, previous linkages remain.

In the end, we are left with Vince and Tom, AND, Bob and Alice being linked as same customers in customer table. So customer table may look like ...

```
CustomerName    Customer Link
------------    -------------
Fred            NULL
Bob             YYYYYY
Vince           XXXXXX
Tom             XXXXXX 
Alice           YYYYYY
```

Comment: Homework disguised as a question?

Comment: @a'b'c'd'e'f'g'h', not much of a disguise here =)

Comment: Interesting question, but is it homework? If so tag it with the homework tag to be fair. Also have you attempted to solve this at all yourself? Is there a particular area you are struggling with?

Comment: It is no homework. I asked this question before in a different language but people could not understand it. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014815/a-very-complicated-sql-query-issue) So I had to simplify it a lot, which now makes it look like homework. I really tried, but I cannot get the logic going. Tom on the other thread took a good shot, but still his logic is not producing the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

The relational operator you require is [division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29), popularly known as ["the supplier who supplies all parts"](http://www.dbdebunk.com/page/page/772076.htm).

Because you consider  Bob who has three rows to be the same as Alice who has only one row, you should be be looking at [division with remainder](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/). Unlike the examples at that link, you need to derive your divisor table from your dividend table `CustomerIdentification`. An empty divisor is not an issue in your case.

Comment: I would appreciated if you could reply with a sample code. I am kinda exhausted with this.

Comment: I apologize onedaywhen. I will read those articles. Its just I have been at it for a week now and I'm kinda brain drained. If someone could come back with a solution that works.... I guess I'm being unreasonable.

Answer (score 1):

I have a question. What should happen if we had these rows:

```
INSERT  [dbo].[CustomerIdentification]
VALUES  
        ('Morheus',   'A',  'Passport'),
        ('Morheus',   'B',  'SIN'),

        ('Neo',       'B',  'SIN'),
        ('Neo',       'C',  'Drivers Licence'),

        ('Trinity',   'C',  'Drivers Licence'),
        ('Trinity',   'A',  'Passport') ;
```

Should they all 3 be placed in the same group (regarded as same customer)?

**EDIT**: OP replied that all 3 should be considered as the same customer.

---

And what should happen in this occasion:

```
INSERT  [dbo].[CustomerIdentification]
VALUES  
        ('Morheus',   'A',  'Passport'),
        ('Morheus',   'B',  'SIN'),

        ('Neo',       'B',  'SIN'),
        ('Neo',       'C',  'Drivers Licence'),

        ('Trinity',   'C',  'Drivers Licence'),
        ('Trinity',   'D',  'Passport') ;       --- the only change from previous
```

Now, `Morheus` should be the same customer as `Neo` (same `SIN`, no other conflicts).

And `Neo` should be the same customer as `Trinity` (same `Drivers Licence`, no other conflicts).

But `Trinity` and `Morheus` have different passports.

**EDIT**: OP replied that all if we examine `Morheus` and `Neo` first, then they should be considered as one. Then, `Trinity` should be rejected as her Passport clashes with `Morheus`.

I assume that if we examine `Neo` and `Trinity` first, then they should be considered as one, and then `Morheus` should be rejected, as his Passport clashes with `Trinity`.

My conclusion is that **the question is ill-defined in relational terms**. It's not solvable using only relational logic. It probably can be solved using variables or analytic extensions e.g. `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for attempting to help with my problem. In your first test case, Morphese and Trinity have same passport with value A, other two IDType SIN and DRIV LIC are different so yes, they are the same customer. Now, for morphese and neo are also same, because they both have SIN B and Passport and Driv License are differnt IDType. But Morphese is already linked to Trin, so we have to bring her into the equation. Since in this case, Trinity does not clash with neo, as both have Driv Lic C and SIN And Passport are different, indeed they are all the same customer and should be linked.

Comment: In your 2nd case, morphese is same as neo, cause both have SIN B and other two are different. So we link them. Now we check neo and trinity, who both have Driv Lic C and other two are different, but Neo is already linked with morphese so we have to bring morphese and see if morphese fits into the equation. But morphese, does not, cause he clashes with trinity Passport A Vs Passport D. So no linking done. End result, only morphese and neo are same customer.

Comment: If you are wondering different order of the data would produce different results, then yes, thats entirely possible. And acceptable in my scenario.

Comment: Wow, I was hoping this problem was not as difficult as I was thinking and that someone will be able to help solve this rather quickly. Guess it is not easy......

Comment: @Vince: It's not very difficult. The problem is that you can have different results based on the order that combinations are checked. SQL and relational operators work when the result is the same, no matter what order is used. So, your question is ill-defined in relational terms.

Comment: I know the order of the data can produce different results, but the problem is not ill-defined considering those results are acceptable.

Comment: Yes, I meant *"ill-defined in **relational terms**"*. It can probably be more easily solved using procedural logic. Or a combination of relational (using the division operator) and procedural logic.

Comment: So my new best friend, what do you suggest?

Comment: I never said it has to be solved using 'only' relational logic. I just want it solved!!

Comment: Come on please, dont bail on me using "the question is ill-defined" excuse.......

Comment: @Vince: I've upvoted this answer because it's probably about as good as you can expect from such a forum i.e. top class analysis even if you didn't get a working solution. I'm tempted to delete my answer but I agree that division may provide a partial solution or maybe just a clue. I may even come back to this one when I have some time to spare, it's foxed me for the moment but I feel it should be soluble using relational operators alone... ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had a second look but didn't get far…

First, fix the design from EAV to something 'more relational' (includes nulls but never mind!):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Customers
(
  CustomerName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  Passport CHAR(1), 
  SIN CHAR(1), 
  Drivers_Licence CHAR(1), 
  Credit_Card CHAR(1)
) ;

INSERT INTO dbo.Customers (CustomerName, Passport, SIN, Drivers_Licence, Credit_Card) 
   VALUES ('Fred', 'A', 'A', 'A', NULL),
          ('Bob', 'A', NULL, 'B', 'C'), 
          ('Vince', 'A', 'B', NULL, 'C'),
          ('Tom', 'A', 'B', 'A', NULL), 
          ('Alice', NULL, NULL, 'B', NULL);
```

Next, self-join to find pairs of customers that have at least one matching attribute:

```
SELECT c1.CustomerName, c2.CustomerName
  FROM dbo.Customers c1
       JOIN dbo.Customers c2
          ON c1.CustomerName < c2.CustomerName
             AND (
                  c1.Credit_Card = c2.Credit_Card
                  OR c1.Drivers_Licence = c2.Drivers_Licence
                  OR c1.Passport = c2.Passport
                  OR c1.SIN = c2.SIN
                 );
```

Whittle this down further by customer pairs that don't have contradictory data, giving 'benefit of the doubt' for nulls:

```
SELECT c1.CustomerName, c2.CustomerName
  FROM dbo.Customers c1
       JOIN dbo.Customers c2
          ON c1.CustomerName < c2.CustomerName
             AND (
                  c1.Credit_Card = c2.Credit_Card
                  OR c1.Drivers_Licence = c2.Drivers_Licence
                  OR c1.Passport = c2.Passport
                  OR c1.SIN = c2.SIN
                 )
INTERSECT
SELECT c1.CustomerName, c2.CustomerName
  FROM dbo.Customers c1
       JOIN dbo.Customers c2
          ON c1.CustomerName < c2.CustomerName
             AND COALESCE(c1.Credit_Card, c2.Credit_Card, 'x') 
                    = COALESCE(c2.Credit_Card, c1.Credit_Card, 'x') 
             AND COALESCE(c1.Drivers_Licence, c2.Drivers_Licence, 'x')
                    = COALESCE(c2.Drivers_Licence, c1.Drivers_Licence, 'x')
             AND COALESCE(c1.Passport, c2.Passport, 'x')
                    = COALESCE(c2.Passport, c1.Passport, 'x')
             AND COALESCE(c1.SIN, c2.SIN, 'x')
                    = COALESCE(c2.SIN, c1.SIN, 'x');
```

This results in three pairs:

```
CustomerName         CustomerName
-------------------- --------------------
Alice                Bob
Bob                  Vince
Tom                  Vince
```

Next, we need to eliminate the pair Bob and Vince based on the logic, "Bob is already linked to Alice so we have to bring Alice into the picture. And Vince is already linked to Tom so we have to bring Tom into the picture," which suggests recursion or hierarchical (finding trees in forests?), at which point I bow out.

Comment: Hi onedaywhen, I think if you look at the other thread I posted in one of my responses, Tom actually did the same without even changing the table design. Besides, I must add, changing the table design is not an option. I am given the databsae design by a 3rd party vendor and it cannot be changed. Thanks for you attempt, I know it is a very peculiar problem. I consider myself pretty good at SQL but even I am stumped for a week now.

Comment: @Vince: "Tom actually did the same without even changing the table design" -- you can transform the third party's 'EVA' structure in my 'more relational' one in a query (e.g. VIEW) e.g. using PIVOT. But are you even aware that Tom's answer opens with the line, "I've changed your data model a bit..." !

Comment: He changed the basic data types and column names but fundamentally his tables represented what mine did. BTW, I did manage to solve the problem.